# Tax File Number Encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, encryption

I'm currently writing an app where I have to store a persons Tax File Number (Australia) securely. Currently it stores in plain text and only shows the last few digits to a user.

What would the best encryption be for storing the number?

Alternatively, are there any best practises when storing a tax file number on a database?

Comment: I assume a competent lawyer has examined your legal obligations with regards to how the TFN is stored?

Comment: Compliance and rules information is available from the ATO: http://www.oaic.gov.au/law/tax-file-numbers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you need the number for. Ideally, if you don't need to display the number but only use it for validation or identification then a one way encryption would be best (perhaps a hash). It really depends on what you need the number for.

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm not too sure, but we still need to display part of the number. It seems that encrypting it seems pretty pointless but apparently it has to be stored as securely as possible.

Comment: Adding encryption to your application will definitively increase the complexity but since your application deals with sensitive data I believe it's a unfortunate necessity.

Comment: @Domness If you only need the last few digits, if possible only store the last few digits. The only people who have a legitimate need to take TFNs in Australia are financial institutions and employers anyway.

Comment: I've just spoke to them, and it's definitely needed in full for the future. I guess the only solution is a two-way hash?

Comment: No such thing as a two way hash, if you absolutely need the whole number use some form of encryption but be careful, it's usually a bad idea to keep such sensitive information in a database .

Comment: Yeh, I can understand, but how would it be stored otherwise?

Comment: Well it really depends on what it's needed for. Perhaps you can use a surrogate instead of the actual number, a one way hash, etc. really depends on what it will be used for. I don't know about regulations about TFNs in Australia but there might be regulations about their collection and storage as well.

Comment: @Domness There are some serious rules about how to use and store TFNs. See http://www.oaic.gov.au/law/tax-file-numbers.html .